# Can we create console or React apps in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I just got a tip of day in android which says "Android Studio provides several kotlin project types:" . But I search everywhere in Android studio and internet what no findings till now.

[Tip of Day in Android Studio.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8QXK.png)

I searched in Android Studio to find such templates, and also searched in plugins but no findings.

Comment: Any body who understands question and tip shown by Android Studio please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

This tip is hopelessly outdated. You could create a module based on standard templates or you could use project templates in the vanilla Intellij IDA and then move generated files into Android Studio.